# Python NameError with write function?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I have Python 3.4 and this is a function that write a file:

```
def wr1(filename,L):
    f = open(filename, 'w')

    for list in L:
        for line in list:
            word=line + ';'
        f.write(word[:len(write)-1])

    f.close
    return L
```

L is a list of list of chars. The problem that I have is the error:

```
NameError: name 'write' is not defined
```

But write is a method of files... Any solution?

Comment: It's referring to the `write` in `len(write)`.  What do you intend to take the length of?  Did you mean `len(list)`?

Comment: Also, when you fix this problem, you're immediately going to run into several more. Please attempt to solve those on your own before asking us. (I'll point out a few - you're not calling the method when you write `f.close`, and your inner loop throws away the previous value of `word` on every iteration - but please don't leave a series of comments asking us how to solve each successive problem.)

Comment: Do not call a variable `list`, it is already taken (`list()` coerces the argument to type list).